# SVN Project to C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt, subversive

Since I [cant't create C++ project from sources in SVN anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487128/check-out-as-project-configured-using-the-new-project-wizard-creates-empty-pro) I'm thinking about checkout project from SVN as simple Project and then try to convert this project to C++ project with SVN linkage. Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: have you tried editing the solution and project files with text editor for converting it into c++ project?

Comment: no, I expect this is not "official" and might cause some problems

Comment: @DhyanDeepA.K eclipse does not have solution files...

Comment: If you checkout the code via eclipse/subversive, eclipse should know already where you got the sources from. Why should your project itself then have any coupling so SVN? If of relevance, I'd rather add the project files themselves to SVN, then you can check them out, too, and use eclipse's "import existing projects" feature. Additional advantage: all your protect's compiler settings are saved with, too.

Comment: Just create a normal C++ project and then add it to SVN outside of Eclipse, for example using TortoiseSVN. Make sure to include `.project`, `.cproject` and `.settings` (folder) in SVN.

Comment: I already have source in SVN and can't add to it.  And I don't thing  adding`.project` `.cproject` `.settings` to SVN is good idea